# Match criteria between two tables to find maximum date within a list

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-match

I have 2 tables of data, one is only 5 columns and the second is 100s of columns, but in simplistic terms they have the formatting below. Both are hundreds of rows long.

Table 1 (is sorted ascending, all columns)

```
        A       B       C       D       E
    1   Date    TeamF   Trans   Name    TeamT
    2   date1   teamF1  trans1  name1   teamT1
    3   date2   teamF2  trans2  name2   teamT2
    4   date3   teamF3  trans3  name3   teamT3
    5   date4   teamF4  trans4  name4   teamT4
    6   date5   teamF5  trans5  name5   teamT5
```

Table 2 (not sorted in any manner)

```
        A       B       C       D       E       F       G       ,etc.
    1   Team    Game    Date    Opp     NameA   NameB   NameC   ,etc...
    2   team1   game1   date1   opp1    statsA1 statsB1 statsC1 ,etc...
    3   team2   game2   date2   opp2    statsA2 statsB2 statsC2 ,etc...
    4   team3   game3   date3   opp3    statsA3 statsB3 statsC3 ,etc...
    5   team4   game4   date4   opp4    statsA4 statsB4 statsC4 ,etc...
    6   team5   game5   date5   opp5    statsA5 statsB5 statsC5 ,etc...
```

I've been trying to get the `INDEX/MATCH` formula I typically use (below) a little more sophisticated to avoid some errors I've been having in data processing. I'm trying to pull the `TeamT` name from Table 1 and populate the `stats` rows in Table 2, columns E and beyond. I do this based on a

1. match of `Names` between Table1 column D and Table 2 row 1
2. `Dates` in Table 1 being <= `Dates` in Table 2 column C
   with the following formula

my current formula `=INDEX(Table1!$A:$E,MATCH(1,(Table1!$D:$D=Table2!E$1)*(Table1!$A:$A<=Table2!$C2),0),5)`

As you can probably see, if there are multiple dates in Table 1 that are less than C2, I only get the first one. What I'd really like is the maximum (newest one). I've been playing with `MAX/IF` statements and `INDEX/MATCH/IF` statements but can't get the proper result. Some examples of those failed tries are below

example 1 
`=MAX(IF(Table1!$D:$D=Table2!E$1,IF(Table1!$A:$A<=Table2!$C2,Table1!$E:$E)))`

example 2 
`=INDEX(Table1!$E:$E,MATCH(MAX(IF(Table1!$D:$D=Table2!E$1,Table1!$A:$A<=Table2!$C2)),IF(Table1!$D:$D=Table2!E$1,Table1!$A:$A<=Table2!$C2),0))`

Any help would be appreciated. I've tried many solutions I've found, but I'm still pulling my hair out on this one.

I also have a second variation of formula where I match dates based on `Dates` in Table 1 being >= `Dates` in Table 2 column C. In that case I want the minimum match (the oldest date). I'm assuming I'd simply use `MIN` instead of `MAX` for this?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, here I have the answer for your first question.

[image]

To make the sample easier, I put everything in one sheet.  You can copy to the new sheet once you are happy with the result.  That way you will have the working formula.

The array formula (click <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> together) I used from `cell K2` is:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($E$2:$E$11,MATCH(MAX(IF(--($D$2:$D$11=K$1)*--($A$2:$A$11<$I2)*$A$2:$A$11,$A$2:$A$11)),IF(--($D$2:$D$11=K$1)*--($A$2:$A$11<$I2)*$A$2:$A$11,$A$2:$A$11),0)),"")
```

You can drag this to the fields you need.  Please note this to find the most current date.  Because I am not 100% sure this is what you are looking for.  Therefore, in my example from `cell O2`, I managed to find the latest row and the formula (regular formula) is:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($E$2:$E$11,LOOKUP(2,1/(--($D$2:$D$11=O$1)*--($A$2:$A$11<$I2)),(ROW($E$2:$E$11)-ROW(O$1)))),"")
```

For the 2nd question, I will leave it to you to find out from these two and that should do the trick.

Comment: Many thanks. Your solution worked to find a date, but not always the most current one. I discovered a new solution after working with the MAXIFS function to find the most current date, and paired it with a multi criteria VLOOKUP function. I'll post the result in the post here.

Comment: Too bad that my Excel doesn't have `MAXIFS` to test.  But the array formula (the 1st one or the one used in `columns K, L and M`) should work fine for your situation.  But I noticed one difference is the `<=` in your question/answer that I missed the `=` sign in my formula.  Or do you mind to provide some examples so I know where the problem is in my formula so it can be improved next time?

Answer (score 0):

I worked this out myself with MAXIFS to find the max date and a multi-criteria VLOOKUP function

this finds the max date less than a current row based on a name match

`=VLOOKUP(MAXIFS(Table1!$A:$A,Table1!$D:$D,E$1,Table1!$A:$A,"<="&$C2)&E$1,CHOOSE({1,2},Table1!$A:$A&Table1!$D:$D,Table1!$E:$E),2,0)`

the solution to a min date greater than the current row based on a name match is

`=VLOOKUP(MINIFS(Table1!$A:$A,Table1!$D:$D,E$1,Table1!$A:$A,">="&$C2)&E$1,CHOOSE({1,2},Table1!$A:$A&Table1!$D:$D,Table1!$B:$B),2,0)`